# how to uppercase all the String elements of backbone serialized form

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, serialization, uppercase, syphon

When i submit a form i send a serialized object to the server.
But before sending it i need to uppercase all its input elements.

this is a piece of my code:

```
submitForm: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this);
    console.log(data);// here i need to uppercase all data elements
    this.trigger("form:submit", data);
},
```

I need to do this before sending it to thserver and not in the backend.
Any solution to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is a array of object you need to iterate each object and use the method `toUpperCase()`, example:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    console.log(value.toUpperCase());
});
```